# Gradle sync failed on android studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-4.0

After upgrading my android project to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'` 
and `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

I found this error

**Gradle sync failed: Cause: org/gradle/api/internal/java/usagecontext/LazyConfigurationUsageContext**

my project details is:

compileSdkVersion 29

ndkVersion "21.1.6352462"

minSdkVersion 21

targetSdkVersion 29

How I can solve this problem, on android studio 4.0?

Comment: do you get any solution?

Comment: @zihadrizkyef  yes, by downgrading  Android Gradle Plugin  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'` and `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Switch to gradle version 5.6.4. LazyConfigurationUsageContext doesn't have support in gradle versions 6.0+.

Comment: how I can remove LazyConfigurationUsageContext  from my application, I want to use latest gradle version?

Comment: //apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
   //classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.1'
after removing these lines project successfully upgraded to latest gradle plugin of android studio

Comment: @AbdurRehman you are correct. I remove these lines as I have them on my project and the error disappear.