# How to remove lazyconfigurationusagecontext from my android project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-studio-4.0

```
compileSdkVersion 29
ndkVersion "21.3.6528147"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

This is my project details,

I'm getting Gradle sync failed on android studio 4.0.0 due to usage of `LazyConfigurationUsageContext`,

How I can found `LazyConfigurationUsageContext` in my project to remove.

I want to use latest gradle version, not give me answer to downgrade gradle version as in this link

[Gradle sync failed on android studio 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146334/gradle-sync-failed-on-android-studio-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

After a long time I found a solution of it
I removed these lines from my project

```
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.1'
```

after removing these lines project successfully upgraded to latest gradle plugin of android studio